# Software removed from Honda 2017 radio

Tags: honda, audio, software

I'm from Poland.
I removed the software from the radio in Honda Accord Hybrid 2017.
Only the reversing camera works.
The service in Poland will not help me, because the car is from the USA.
Does anyone have such software? can help me?
In Poland there is an android, but I need iOS.

Comment: I found [system update page](https://usb.honda.com/consumer/landing) and [documentation](http://owners.honda.com/Documentum/ota/2018_Accord_Sedan.pdf).